# Array of optimizers

Tags: optimization, tensorflow

I want to test a tensorflow classifier with several optimizers. With this code :

```
optimizers = [
tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
tf.train.ProximalGradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)]

for optimizer in optimizers:
    print(optimizer)
```

I got this error :

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Any help please.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible within a single session to have multiple optimizers without getting their updates mixed and meddled up. Also, could you please post what code results in that error? Does the creation of the `optimizers` array cause the error or something else which happens later in your code?

Comment: It's possible to start and close session every loop.

Comment: It must be something else, I can't reproduce the error. Your code shows me all the optimizers printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) on tensorflow.org and combining this with your array of optimizers I can obtain all accuracy rates. The error message you get seems to come from a different place.

**Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
learning_rate = 0.5

optimizers = [
    tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
    tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
    tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
    tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
    tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
    tf.train.ProximalGradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
    tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy),
    tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)]

for optimizer in optimizers:
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for _ in range(1000):
      batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
      sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

**Output:**
    0.9157
    0.8832
    0.9169
    0.098
    0.917
    0.9149
    0.917
    0.098

Comment: Well, the learning rate was the same, but some optimizers have a recommended learning rate (it is the case of AdamOptimizer, for instance) and others work better with another parameter (like decay in RMSPropOptimizer, for intance). Both examples with the worst results.

Comment: @EduardoFreitas This question was not about results but about the technical problem of looping through optimizers.

Comment: Hi @TheWaveLad, that's why I wrote as a comment, not as an answer. The presented code in the question does not show the initialization as your answer shows and it is correct. The observation about the learning rate is only a warning to avoid that someone starts to say that one optimizer is better than other  without consider the recommended initial parameters. That`s it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @EduardoFreitas, you're absolutely right.